# Trying to push to array, overwrites every value

Tags: arrays, ruby, overwrite

I wanted to create an anagram solver. Here's my code:

```
def permut(word)
  for i in 1..$laenge
    if i != $laenge
      word[$laenge-i], word[$laenge-i-1] = word[$laenge-i-1],  word[$laenge-i]
      $output.push word
      $y += 1
    end
  end
end
```

I shouldn't be using global variables, and the `for`-loop in `get_input` will get stuck, but it's just for learning purposes, my focus is just on the array problem and I'm debugging it with rdebug.

When I push the value of the mixed word to an array, it overwrites all values of it. I tried it by giving an index like `Array[y]` and incrementing `y` every time I go through the `for`-loop, or just by using `Array.push`, followed by the word as a string.

Comment: *"my focus is just on the array problem"* - can you shorten your example accordingly? It seems to include code that is not directly related to your problem.

Comment: I know, but I just wanted to give you an overview of the complete code, I will shorten it

Answer (score 1):

You are mutating the very same string over and over.

```
ar = []
word = "abc"
ar.push(word)
word[0], word[1] = word[1], word[0]
p ar # => ["bac"]
```

Try saving duplicates of the mutated string in the array:

```
ar.push(word.dup)
```

Comment: thank you so much! that part now works flawlessly, changed it to word.dup. still hassling with some other stuff, but that's what learning's for.